# $(document).ready(function () does not work

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have the following very simple code:

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert('ghg');
  });
</script>
```

This code does not work, since the alert is not displayed.

However, the following code shows the alert:

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
  alert('ghg');
</script>
```

What it is the problem?

Comment: That means jQuery isn't loaded as of when you run that code, or it's loaded by it doesn't have control of the `$` variable (in that case, try `jQuery(document).ready`...). Are you including jQuery on the page before that code? When you look in the web console, do you see any errors?

Comment: yes I got errors   Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery-ui.min.js:6
    at jquery-ui.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ jquery-ui.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ jquery-ui.min.js:6
jquery-

Comment: You've included jQuery UI, but not jQuery. They're separate scripts.

Comment: T.J. Crowder that was the problem jquery.js was missing thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add Jquery plugin in your code.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert('ghg');
  });
</script>
```